# G++ how to compile for FreeBSD on linux server

Tags: c++, linux, unix, freebsd, ld-preload

I wrote some code for linux/unix(ld_preload), how can i compile it for FreeBSD on my Ubuntu Server using G++, or maybe other compiler?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a cross-compiler; just google this term.

Comment: @H2CO3: If the machines are the same arch, you don't even need that. FreeBSD tries very hard to have binary compatibility with Linux.

Comment: @Linuxios good point, didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

No need to recompile: [there's a shim for the differences](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/linuxemu.html) that's a little more tightly integrated than just a compat library.  Some linux-only facilities you'll need to avoid, and you do need to 'brand' the linux binaries w/ `brandelf`, your starting point is that link.

Comment: +1 for you instead of the ugly VM solution. Much more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to create a FreeBSD virtual machine (using software like virtualbox) and compile the code on that.

Comment: +1: avoids a leap of faith in the cross-compile environment or compat library